# Build cascade controls in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

On this occasion I need someone to guide me, to implement cascading form controls in QGis 2.18. I am using a code for the attributes "area" "county" and "town" to perform a dynamic filter. The problem is, it does not filter the attributes. This is the code, I got it from https://medspx.fr/blog/Qgis/cascade_forms/ by Médéric RIBREUX.

Is it possible to change this code to work with QGIS 3?

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *

myDialog = None

def formOpen(dialog,layerid,featureid):
global myDialog
myDialog = dialog

# We need to introspect the form
# In QGis v2.4 autobuild form controls do not have a name... (fixed in v2.6)
# So we need to retrieve form controls by field order !
lst_children = dialog.findChildren(QComboBox)
area = lst_children[0]
county = lst_children[1]
town = lst_children[2]

# Clear the children QComboBox widgets
county.clear()
town.clear()

# When you change the value for area widget, change the content of the county widget
area.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: cascadeManage('COUNTY', 'ID_COUNTY', 'COUNTY', 'ID_AREA', county, area))
# When you change the value for county widget, change the content of the town widget
county.currentIndexChanged.connect(lambda: cascadeManage('TOWN', 'ID_TOWN', 'TOWN', 'ID_COUNTY', town, county))

def cascadeManage(layername, id_idx, txt_idx, fltr, widget, parent_widget):
'''Generic function to manage cascading QComboBox.
   * layername: the layer (flat table) to request values for this control
   * id_idx: primary key for the table (used in for the form control key)
   * txt_idx: field shown in the form control QComboBox
   * fltr: field which is used to filter the content of this widget based on the parent widget value
   * widget: widget object (QComboBox) to control
   * parent_widget: get the value from the parent QComboBox widget'''
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsExpression

# Get the layer (flat table)
layers = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName(layername)
if (len(layers) > 0):
    layer = layers[0]
else:
    return False

# get attributes indexes
ididx = layer.fieldNameIndex(id_idx)
txtidx = layer.fieldNameIndex(txt_idx)

# Get the value of the parent QComboBox
filter_code = str(parent_widget.itemData(parent_widget.currentIndex()))

# Build an expression with it
exp = QgsExpression("{0} = {1}".format(fltr, filter_code))
exp.prepare(layer.pendingFields())

# clear the current widget content
widget.clear()

# And fill it with filtered data:
for feature in layer.getFeatures():
    value = exp.evaluate(feature)
    if exp.hasEvalError():
        raise ValueError(exp.evalErrorString())
    if bool(value):
        widget.addItem(feature.attributes()[txtidx], feature.attributes()[ididx])
```

Comment: Can you update to QGIS 3.4? I believe cascading forms are now a standard feature.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer, if I have installed QGIS 3.4 and 3.6 and I used the function current_value with the widget value relation. But QGIS closes automatically, when I use more than 2 attributes to perform the dynamic filter. (i.e) if I use the "town" attribute when starting the editing. QGIS crash.

Comment: Please make a bug report: https://issues.qgis.org/

Comment: Thank you. I will do it